# How exactly process stored in memory?

Tags: memory, process, stack, heap-memory, virtual-memory

I understand how the process is stored in the form of pages. Also, the memory layout of a program generally contains the 4 segments i.e. Code segment, data segment, Stack, and heap. But I have some questions while combining the above both things.

1. Do the stack and heap also store in pages? How they get distinguished that particular section is stack and other is the heap?
2. If stack and heap (also the data seg.) is stored in pages then how they get linked to the particular process.
3. Does complete physical memory is divided into pages or only part of memory which stores the code segment? (I am confused because the page frame contains page number and instruction offset and instruction means the code of the program.)
4. Also when we say that there is 4 GB of virtual memory is there in the system then does it mean that for each process it is 4 GB or is it a total 4 GB? And if it is a total 4 GB then isn't it similar to physical memory (RAM)?

Comment: All of this is dependent on the implementation. Please tag with the implementation you are interested in.

Comment: @RaymondChen Actually I am interested in the generic concept of how the program is divided into segments and how all these segments stored in pages. If it differs vastly from OS to OS then its implementation in Linux will be helpful, Thanks..!